# table borders not visible on firefox print

Tags: html, firefox, printing-web-page

I am building a printable table. And it works well on chrome. But on firefox
, it doesn't show the table borders.

```html
    <body>
      <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>One</td><td>One</td><td>One</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>One</td><td>One</td><td>One</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>One</td><td>One</td><td>One</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

        <style>
          table,tr,td{
            border: 1px solid;
            border-collapse: collapse;
          }
        </style>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems they are not visible on the preview usually when the border is too thin like `1px`. But the borders will actually be visible when printed.

This is probably image resampling problem on firefox preview. since they display well on chrome.